# Losing UserControl when editing winForm VS2012

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

I have a Form called `EmployeeForm` inside this form i'm including some UserControl and when I edit `EmployeeForm` every UserControl inside the form are lost.

This picture show a diff between TFS(left) and Local(right) file, after modifying the name of a combobox

[image]

Example of this.ucEmployeeKeyOne :

```
public partial class Employee_EmployeeKeyOneRelationUC
    : Employee_EmployeeKeyOneRelation_GenericUC
{ [other Code Here] }

public class Employee_EmployeeKeyOneRelation_GenericUC
    : RelationUC<MyObject>
{ }
```

and the definition of RelationUC :

```
public partial class RelationUC<T>
    : DataUserControlBase
{ [other Code Here] }

public partial class DataUserControlBase
   : UserControlBase
{ [other Code Here] }

public partial class UserControlBase
   : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl, MyInterfaceHere
{ [other Code Here] }
```

All `UserControl` i'm losing are inherited from `RelationUC<T>`. Does the generic type of RelationUC may cause the problem?

Comment: The designer in the IDE sometimes freaks out. Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: @PaulSasik yes I tried. thanks for the try

Comment: Check to make sure that the UC class you're inheriting from can be properly instantiated by the IDE. E.g. make sure there are public constructors, the classes are not abstract etc. Test this by opening the inherited control directly in the designer.

Comment: I did that too the `RelationUC<T>` shows correctly in the designer.

Comment: How about `DataUserControlBase`? And `Employee_EmployeeKeyOneRelation_GenericUC` ?

Comment: @PaulSasik Edited question. And `Employee_EmployeeKeyOneRelation_GenericUC` definition is in the question. This class is empty, I had to do this to fix another problem with the designer, lol.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28474/discussion-between-paul-sasik-and-pl-audet)

Comment: Are you using a dll from the uc or is it in your project? Try to import the Uc project in your actual Projectorder.

Comment: RelationUC is in the same project but not his parents

Comment: Do your user controls do any "work" in the OnLoad method?

Comment: @BernhardHofmann `RelationUC`, `DataUserControlBase` and `UserControlBase`  has no OnLoad method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Vs designer to load the controls, the control should be able to initialize including all public properties and you must have a empty constructor. If you don't have an empty constructor or have properties that are returning from the inherited nullable class, it is most likely the the designer will crash.

To Debug this,

1) open you project in VS but do not open the file that contains the controls yet;

2) open another VS and attach the process of VS that your project is opened;

3) set the break on exceptions (short cut '<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd>' ) to all (once you become familiar with what exception the designer is throwing, you can set that exception only.);

4) Go to the VS with you project and open the file that contain your user control. when the exception is thrown, the second VS will catch it and tell you exactly why and where.